# PHP file_get_contents problems with $_GET

Tags: php

I have a problem with my website. My website gets a variable and returns a String. What I mean by that is that if you visit my website the code will me only a 3 digit String eg FEG, PSJ, FGT, HJK. I want to take this String using the `file_get_contents` function. But when I do `$con = file_get_contents("http://website.com/test.php?name=George");` it gives me this error

> Warning: file_get_contents("http://website.com/test.php?name=George"): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2

Comment: You can't get the contents of a `PHP` file passing a GET variable in the title. Have you tried using `cURL` instead?

Comment: No, can you send me a link to check it out?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php - I've added an example as per your question as an answer below.

Comment: You *CAN* pass GET variable in url using `file_get_contents`.

Looks more like website.com is down or test.php isn't reachable

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error usually indicates there's something wrong with the `test.php` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using `cURL` instead:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://website.com/test.php?name=George");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;

?>
```